# How one shows $K_{n,m}$ is not planar.

Tags: graph-theory

My professor is lecturing right now on how $K_{3,3}$ is not planar, where planar is defined as follows:

*Definition*: A graph $G$ is called planar if it can be drawn in the plane without any two edges intersecting.

What I'd like to know is is there a general method of detecting whether or not $K_{n,m}$ is planar for all $n$ and $m$?

---

$\dagger$Note: I put "complex analysis" because I feel there is a strong connection between north pole projections of graphs on a sphere are planar.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem

Comment: or note that $K_{2,n}$ is always planar and that $K_{n,m}$ is never planar for both $n,m\geq3$ since it contains $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with complex analysis.

Comment: Please, remove the [tag:complex-analysis] tag, as this question has nothing to do with the theory of functions of complex variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can argue its non-planarity in various ways, but here the easiest one is case-by-case analysis. Let a bipartite graph $G = (V \uplus U, E)$ be $K_{3,3}$ where $V = \{1,2,3\}$ and $U = \{4,5,6\}$. You start with vertices $1,2,4,5$, and there is only one embedding of those into a plane (that is, all others are equivalent).

$\hspace{50pt}$[image: v1245]

Then you add vertex $3$ and there are two choices.

$\hspace{50pt}$[image: v12345]

Whatever you do, there is no place you can put $6$ down.

$\hspace{50pt}$[image: v123456]

Of course, for larger graphs there are better methods, e.g. as @yoyo already pointed out, $K_{0,n}$, $K_{1,n}$, $K_{2,n}$ are always planar and anything bigger is never planar because of the [Kuratowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem) or [Wagner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$