# How to show $K_5$ is not planar?

Tags: graph-theory

Similar to [How one shows $K_{n,m}$ is not planar.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455920/how-one-shows-k-n-m-is-not-planar) and [Prove that $K_{3,3}$ is not planar.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136430/prove-that-k-3-3-is-not-planar?rq=1)

**How does one show that $K_5$ is** *not* **planar?**

One could try demonstrating non-planar drawings, but how do you know that you've not missed a planar drawing.

One could also calculate $V=5$ and $E=10$, but what is $F$?

Comment: Not similar to those posts, there're no efforts showed in this one.

Comment: The number of edges of a planar graph is bounded by 3v - 6. You can get this by applying Euler's formula to a maximal planar graph (can't add more edges), and using the relationship that each face is a triangle, and each edge is an edge of 2 faces.

Comment: Actually $K_5$ has $10$ edges, not $15$.

Answer (score 3):

As Lorenzo said, take the incidence matrix $M=(m_{e,f})$ of a planar connected graph with $n\geq 3$ nodes. Each edge $e$ is surrounded by $\leq 2$ faces and each face $f$ is surrounded by $\geq 3$ edges. So each row of $M$ has most 2 1's and each column has at least 3 1's. Thus $3|F|\leq 2|E|$. By the Eulerian polyhedra formula, $|V|-|E|+|F|=2$, it follows that $|E|\leq 3|V|-6$. So each planar connected graph with 5 vertices has at most 9 edges. But the $K_5$ has ${5\choose 2} = 10$ edges.